# Washing machine not agitating (very loud)

Tags: washing-machine

About a week ago, our washer started making a loud klunk when agitating when it switched directions.  This weekend we noticed that stuff wasn't getting clean.  I started it with nothing in it and after it fills, the agitator barely moves.  I drained it and the agitator seems to spin almost completely free (rarely engages the motor/gears when spun by hand).

So I pull off the agitator and I'm guessing the plastic gear teeth on the agitator is stripped and needs replaced ([image: gear] [image: agitator]).  I just can't tell if the metal part is also stripped or why it stripped (only about 3 years old).

Should I replace the agitator first?  Or is my ignorance of how this works making me miss something?

Maytag MVWX655DW0

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with an LG. If the basket is overloaded too often, the weight stops the agitator spinning and it eventually strips out the plastic teeth inside, especially when it flips back and forth. I'd imagine it's a design decision and saves on repair costs.

The metal teeth still look in good shape from what I can see. It looks like you probably need part W10609480.

When assembling the washer again, clean the bolt with a wire brush or similar and use a little blue Loctite to stop itself working loose.